# How to call the same method from different Classes in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have the same method for different Classes and I'm calling them using ifs. I would like to use a faster approach to do so. 
For instance:

```
Class Car:
  def get_name():
    return 'car'

Class House:
  def get_name():
    return 'house'

Class Airplane:
  def get_name():
    return 'airplane'

# main file
import Car
import House
import Airplane
import sys

c = Car
h = House
a = Airplane

option = sys.argv[0]
if option == 0:
  print c.get_name()
elif option == 1:
  print h.get_name()
elif option == 2:
  print a.get_name()
```

Is there a way to call a method from a specific class, avoiding using ifs?

This is just a simple example for what I am trying to achieve. I have a bunch of classes which are already standardized, having the same methods. I guess this is Polymorphism, but I am not sure about how to make it work in this specific case, for faster for a better performance. That's what I am trying to achieve: a better performance. Thank you.

**Edit 1**

It is not sys.argv which determines the chosen class, its the result of some calculations. For example, the item that has the highest volume. This is just an example to simplify my algorithm.

**Edit 2**
I am combining multiple APIs, each has its own Class file with the same methods which I've managed to return the same values (of course, with network data). I call the method from all Classes first, like get_price() and compare them. For the one which has the lowest price, I want to call get_name(), without using ifs...

Comment: Why exactly are you using classes for this? You don't appear to actually be creating any instances, so you're just using them as namespaces....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a tuple and take advantage of its indexing:

```
Class Car:
  def get_name():
    return 'car'

Class House:
  def get_name():
    return 'house'

Class Airplane:
  def get_name():
    return 'airplane'

# main file
import Car
import House
import Airplane
import sys

classes = Car, House, Airplane

option = sys.argv[0]  # perhaps you wanted to use sys.argv[1] ?
print classes[int(option)].get_name()
```

---

## EDIT 0

As pointed out by @MarcoBonelli , please keep in mind that `sys.argv[0]` is the name of your script and unless you named your script as a number, e.g. `1`, this is likely not what you want. To get the first argument passed to your script use `sys.argv[1]`.

---

## EDIT 1

Based on your edits, perhaps you are better off with a `dict`.
The idea is the same as for the tuple, but you have a better control of what to use for triggering the choice of the `class`.
This can be used like this:

```
classes = {'c': Car, 'h': House, 'a': Airplane}

key = 'c'
classes[key].get_name()
# car
```

note that the key can be any hashable.

---

## EDIT 2

This question is a bit of a moving target... anyway, based on your last edits, this is how I would do it:

```
classes = Car, House, Airplane
prices = [x.get_price() for x in classes]
min_price = min(prices)  # if you need this for later, otherwise just inline with following
i = prices.index(min_price)  # index at which the minimum is found
classes[i].get_name()
```

Comment: well, nothing is preventing you to call your script, say `1`, admittedly quite unlikely but you never know. Students can be very creative. :-)

Comment: True, but that'd probably be `1.py`, no? :P

Comment: @MarcoBonelli the Python interpreter wouldn't complain about the missing `.py` though and the original post did not indicate that part to have problems.

Answer (score 0):

*Edited to address your latest clarification.*

You can use a simple tuple:

```
classes = (Car, House, Airplane)
option = 1 # just as an example

print classes[option].get_name()
```

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring some issues in your question (such as none of these methods being `staticmethod` or `classmethod` when they probably want to be), then if you wish to call `get_name` on the type with the lowest `get_price`, then something like:

```
min( (x.get_price(), x) for x in (Car, House, Airplane) )[1].get_name()
```

should do what you want.

Here we:

- find the minimum pair `(<type>.get_price(), <type>)`, leveraging that the comparison of tuples compares element wise; then
- we take the corresponding type from that pair and invoke `get_name`.

**NOTE:** In this example, if two `get_price` both return the exact same minimum value, then the one chosen will be rather random, depending on the comparison of the types.